# Where can I find all of the crafting patterns?

Tags: the-secret-world

Is there a help menu hidden away somewhere in the game that I haven't found which lists the various shapes needed to craft various kinds of weapons, glyphs, and talismans?

I know that there were handy diagrams in the books that were used as part of the crafting tutorials at the Sheriff's Office and in the Fortune Tellers House, but is there any way I can pull those up for reference now, long after having done those quests? I can't even go back to those locations and look at the books anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out theses images in the journal (finished quest). For full information about crafting, shapes and much more i recommend this resource:

http://yokaiblog.wikidot.com/guides:craft-patterns

Answer (score 3):

The only place in the game that those crafting patterns can be found is in those quests.  **You can look them up in the 'finished missions' section of your journal, and pull up the images again by looking under the Tier 1 mission details.**  Glyphs are easy to remember, but this is handy for weapons.  That quest is *Zen and the Art of Weapon Maintenance*, so it's probably the verrry last thing in your Finished Missions list.

I do not believe there are quests at present that lists patterns for gadgets, consumables, or sigils, so you'll just have to memorize these or get them out of game.  (There was a good thread listing them all on the old forums, but I haven't found it archived yet; I'll update this with an out of game link when I find one).

Answer (score 1):

There is [a document on Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Xhlgqh70yUNfYQVnUA3MW4STWqHvQJL2RLcfp7UJiKc/preview?sle=true) that I have been referencing over the last few days which details assembly patterns for weapons, armour, potions, etc.

It also includes information on which materials influence which statistics on the completed item in the case of glyphs.